# Print elements in a vector contiguously

Tags: rust

I would like to know which is the most idiomatic Rust way to print the elements in a vector in a contigously manner. For example, in the following code:

```rust
fn main() {
    let vector = vec![0x54, 0xaf, 0x5c];
    println!("{:2x?}", vector);
}
```

I would like to print: `54af5c` and not `[54, af, 5c]`.

Comment: you can loop over the vector and call print! instead of println!. If you have any more questions i can add a code sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this in one line without multiple calls to the `print!` macro you could do it like so:

```rust
fn main() {
    let vector = vec![0x54, 0xaf, 0x5c];
    println!("{}", vector.iter().map(|n| format!("{:x}", n)).fold(String::new(), |acc, arg| acc + arg.as_str()));
}
```

Here is the [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=65f96609a0b7c646123dc66c49c3e4a5).

This also has the added benefit, that there can be differently formatted hexadecimal numbers in your vector and you can always format them as either [`LowerHex`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.LowerHex.html) or [`UpperHex`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.UpperHex.html).